# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, gpu, cuda

System Spec:

OS: ubuntu 18.04 GPU:

Quadro RTX 4000

I have a fresh installed machine with ubuntu 18.04. To install CUDA 11 toolkit these are the command that i ran :

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin

sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600

sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/ /"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

After installation it show this:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEsY8.png)

My `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`
[dpkg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iODlx.png)

Comment: I assume you actually do have the updated drivers installed?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`?

Comment: i just follow the step from the link sir.

Comment: You have to install the Nvidia drivers.  Have you done that and can you provide the output of the command?  Edit your question and provide the necessary information to answer your question, just saying you followed the instructions, won't be enough information to answer you question.

Comment: @Ramhound ive just updated the output `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` in the question https://i.stack.imgur.com/iODlx.png

Comment: The moderator [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-16-04/48635) seems to suggest removing multiple Nvidia drivers install might solve this problem.  It does appear you have two different versions of the drivers installed.  Once you follow the process to uninstall all Nvidia drivers from your installation you will have to install them again from the Nvidia website.